# How can I wait until AdMob ad has ended to run SKScene transition?

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, admob, skscene, sktransition

I'm implementing AdMob ad's to my game project. I would like the ad to run first and then after the user is done watching the ad and is back to the game, I would like to run the transition. Now however the transition is being run simultaneusly with the ad and that looks bad. My code is as follows. ALL HELP APPRECIATED!

```
if interstitial.isReady {
                interstitial.presentFromRootViewController(self.gameViewController!)
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:getTransition())
            } else {
                print("Ad wasn't ready")
                self.view?.presentScene(scene, transition:getTransition())
            }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AdMob has delegates that you should be using,  It is called `GADInterstitialDelegate`.  That will tell you when certain events in the ad process are happening.

You may want to be looking at the `interstitialDidDismissScreen(ad:GASInterstitial)` method to achieve what you want